# Optimizer internal error while loading data from U-SQL table

Tags: azure-data-lake, u-sql

Is there a way to get around this error.

> "CQO: Internal Error - Optimizer internal error. Assert:
>   a_drgcidChild->CLength() == UlSafeCLength(popMS->Pdrgcid()) in
>   rlstreamset.cpp:499"

Facing this issue while loading data from partitioned U-SQL table.

```
@myData =
    SELECT *
    FROM dbo.MyTable;
```

Comment: Can you share with us an anonymised script or repro of the issue?  Otherwise consider raising a help request via the portal.

Comment: I updated the question with the SELECT statement

Comment: Is there any other information that you think might be useful for this question?  eg the `CREATE TABLE` script (anonymised if needs be), the number of records in each partition, some sample data maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you encounter any system error message (or something that says Internal Error), please open a support ticket with us and/or send me your job link (if it happens on the cluster) or a self-contained smallest repro (if it is happening with local run) to usql at microsoft dot com.

Thanks
Michael

**UPDATE:** This issue has been fixed and will be made available in the next refresh. If you are blocked, please contact me for a private runtime.