# Optimizer internal error in Azure Data Lake with LEFT join

Tags: azure-data-lake

I submitted a new join in Azure Data Lake and got CQO: Internal Error - Optimizer internal error when I use left join or outer join in my U-SQL script. I tried to use inner join instead of left join and also tried to use left join in COSMOS. Both cases are working fine. Can anyone tell me why left join doesn't work in Azure Data Lake? Any help will be appreciated. Also attached screenshot with job link in case somebody needed. screenshot [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yBSSu.png)

Comment: Are the datatypes and nullability of the two columns you are trying to join the same?  It would be helpful if you could share the U-SQL script, remove any business-sensitive data / columns names etc

Comment: U-SQL does support `LEFT JOIN`.  The error message suggests contacting support so that is the best thing to do, as per Michael's notes [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44519306/optimizer-internal-error-while-loading-data-from-u-sql-table/44635074#44635074).

Comment: Thanks for the reply Bob, the problem has been solved. ADL so far doesn't support the FETCH...OFFSET with LEFT JOIN, we can use ROW_NUMBER() with condition instead of FETCH...OFFSET then we can use LEFT JOIN.